# My events are not being counted within Google Analytics

Tags: events, google-tag-manager

I will try to exemplify my problem in the best possible way.

I am not responsible for adding code to the site. Most of the events were added via code, not by GTM. The problem is that they do not fire and do not count within GA.

My doubts are:

1 - Why do events not appear in GA?

2 - Even if the events were implemented directly in the code, is it possible to see it in the GTM debug?

3 - How can I check if these events really exist inside the code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you added the correct tracking ID as a Tag in Tag Manager?

[image]

2. Not sure here
3. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> when you are on the page, where the code is supposed to be. You will open the Inspect tool. You will see a lot of code there, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and searching for your code.

Comment: I suggest using Tag Manager for everything. Setting up triggers is pretty easy, and you won't have to rely on developers - that will save days or maybe weeks of progress.